# Expo Multiple Local Notifications Not Triggering On Time

Tags: expo, react-native, expo-notifications, react-native-notifications

Expo multiple local notifications aren't triggering on time. I am receiving only first notification on time while the others at times trigger a bit late or simultaneously. Few times they do get trigger on time but why I am facing such inconsistency in results

```
CPH1911:
Notification scheduled for: Mon Jan 25 2021 20:07:47 GMT+0500 (PKT)
CPH1911:
Notification scheduled for: Mon Jan 25 2021 20:08:47 GMT+0500 (PKT)
CPH1911:
Notification scheduled for: Mon Jan 25 2021 20:09:47 GMT+0500 (PKT)
CPH1911:
Notification received at: Mon Jan 25 2021 20:07:47 GMT+0500 (PKT)
CPH1911:
ExponentPushToken[NmECbXMqBlCq4nyVeqYFxK]
CPH1911:
Notification received at: Mon Jan 25 2021 20:10:01 GMT+0500 (PKT)
2
```

Following is the snack: (expo sdk version 40, expo-notifications version 0.8.2)

https://snack.expo.io/@rabiarashid/notifications5799